# Jquery validation rules, after submit, checking "retype-password" first (only if we type mismacth password in both fields & other fields are empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

[image]I am using "jquery validation rules"

**my jquery validation rules working fine during blur & tab.. but problem is.. after click on submit, its giving first preference to check password & confirm password.. then it goes to validate another fields.. how can i solve this?**

**screenshot is of during on click of submit button.. after clicking on submit.. its giving first preference to confirm-password check instead of sequencial check.. why its happening**

**after click on submit.. it should validate from top to bottom fields.. but its validating confirm-password field first**

for form validation, but during validation check its checking "retype-password" means "equalTo" attribute first (only if we type mismacth password in both fields & other fields are empty)

Its checking "retype-password" first.. then checks other fields..

I want to validation checking preferences as per form field positions

You can see the issue in screenshot clearly.. "jquery validation rules" checking "retype-password" first (only if we type mismacth password in both fields & other fields are empty).. during that its not showing other validation error messages. If both password fields matches then its showing validation error messages for remaining form fields.

My Code Snippet:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
      }, "Letters only please");

    $('#signup').validate({
        onblur: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: function(element) {
          this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            "first_name": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              maxlength: 15,
              lettersonly: true
            },
            "last_name": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              maxlength: 15,
              lettersonly: true
            },
            "mobile_no": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              minlength: 10,
              maxlength: 10,
              digits: true
            },
            "email": {
              required: {
                    depends:function(){
                        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                        return true;
                    }
              },
              email: true
            },
            "password": { 
              required: true,
              minlength: 4,
              maxlength: 4,
              digits: true
            },
            "conf_password": {
              required: true,
              equalTo: "#mainpassword"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "first_name": {
              required: "First Name is required",
              maxlength: "First Name should be less than 15 characters"
            },
            "last_name": {
              required: "Last Name is required",
              maxlength: "First Name should be less than 15 characters"
            },
            "mobile_no": {
              required: "Mobile No is required",
              minlength: "Mobile No should be a 10-digit number",
              maxlength: "Mobile No should be a 10-digit number",
              digits: "Mobile No should contain only numbers"
            },
            "email": {
              required: "Email is required",
              email: "Invalid email Id"
            },
            "password": {
              required: "Password is required",
              minlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              maxlength: "Password should be a 4-digit number",
              digits: "Password should contain only numbers"
            },
            "conf_password": {
              required: "Confirm Password is required",
              equalTo: "Password mismatch"
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop:  $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top-100
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

please suggest me changes to avoid this issue..

(in screenshot, just showing some part of form)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/xfq73z59/  Please show the relevant HTML and do a better job explaining this issue.

Comment: my jquery validation rules working fine during blur & tab.. but problem is.. its giving first preference to check password & confirm password.. then it goes to validate another fields.. how can i solve this?

Comment: Again, your problem description makes absolutely no sense.  Validation only happens exactly where the user is working.  If the user is interacting with field "xyz" then validation is only done on field "xyz".  If the user clicks on the submit button, then the entire form, all fields, are validated ***simultaneously***.  So please explain exactly how would I trigger a validation message to appear on field `"abc"` while am I actually interacting with field `"xyz"`?

Comment: Please edit your OP to include the ***exact steps*** one must take to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is very unclear.

> You can see the issue in screenshot clearly.. "jquery validation rules" checking "retype-password" first (**only if we type mismacth password in both fields & other fields are empty**).. during that its not showing other validation error messages. If both password fields matches then its showing validation error messages for remaining form fields.

**It's not supposed to show errors for any other fields until the submit button is pressed** or the user directly interacts with those other fields.  Errors are only shown for one field as the user interacts with that one field.  For example, if you are interacting with the `xyz` field and violate validation, then only the error for `xyz` field would be shown.

If they skip over a "required" field, a "required" message will not be shown until the submit button is pressed.  ONLY the submit button can trigger validation messages for all fields on the entire form.

Otherwise I think you might be complaining about "eager" validation, which you've caused here...

```
onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
},
```

If you simply remove this option entirely, you will revert back to the default behavior of "lazy" validation, where validation is ignored until the submit button is clicked for the first time.

For this one...

```
onblur: true
```

There is no such option in the plugin called `onblur`.   It's called `onfocusout`, and you're already using it.   I suggest you [read the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout) because these events (`onfocusout`, `onkeyup`, `onclick`) absolutely can never be set to `true`.

And finally, as far as your picture, **I cannot reproduce** based on your description and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/7yLhs96c/

---

**EDITED with explanation and solution:**

OP's new jsFiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/hirayrakesh04/c1q207zw/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/hirayrakesh04/c1q207zw/6/)

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Enter `1234` in "password" field, leave rest of form blank.
2. Enter `123` in "confirm password" field.
3. Click submit button.

Note that only the error message for "confirm password" appears, but yet this is when all messages on the form should have also appeared.

**Explanation of problem**:

1. "Confirm password" field loses focus when submit button is initially engaged with the `mousedown` event.  This triggers validation for the "confirm password" field as expected.
2. A validation message appears next to "confirm password" field and it pushes the submit button over to make room for this message.
3. Since submit button is now pushed out of the way, the `mouseup` event can not occur for the button click and the submission never happens, therefore the rest of the form is not validated.

**Solution would be to fix the layout so the submit button could never be pushed out from under the mouse during any part of the button click.**

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/c0345gLo/](https://jsfiddle.net/c0345gLo/)**

Comment: thanks for answer.. my jquery validation rules working fine during blur & tab.. but problem is.. its giving first preference to check password & confirm password.. then it goes to validate another fields.. how can i solve this?

Comment: @RakeshHiray, I don't think you understand how form validation is supposed to work, and I don't believe you actually read my answer: *"Errors are only shown for one field as the user interacts with that one field. For example, if you are interacting with the xyz field and violate validation, then only the error for xyz field would be shown."*

Comment: sorry for unclear question, its working properly during blur & tab.. screenshot is of during on click of submit button.. after clicking on submit.. its giving first preference to confirm-password check instead of sequencial check.. why its happening

Comment: after click on submit.. it should validate from top to bottom fields.. but its validating confirm-password field first

Comment: @RakeshHiray, your assumption is completely false.  When you click the submit, **ALL FIELDS will be validated SIMULTANEOUSLY**, which is what I've already stated several times and show in this demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/7yLhs96c/  ~  In other words, when you click `submit` ANY and ALL fields that are not yet valid will be validated at once, and all validation messages will appear **at the SAME TIME**.  Unless there is some other code you have not shown us, the problem **cannot be reproduced**.  I suggest that you take my jsFiddle and edit it to show us the problem.

Comment: thanks bro.. here is my jsfiddle link.. https://jsfiddle.net/hirayrakesh04/c1q207zw/6/ in which directly type "1234" in password & "123" in retype-password & then click on submit.. there is issue

Comment: @RakeshHiray, you cannot complete the click of the submit because the button is forced to jump out of the way for the initial validation message.  See my edited answer above.  **Fix the problem by fixing your layout... the submit button should never be forced to jump out from under the mouse.**